# How to add left and right padding to ::webkit-scrollbar-thumb?

Tags: html, css, sass, scrollbar

Is there a way to replicate YouTube's custom scrollbar?

*Desired effect:*

[image: yt scrollbar]

It seems like ::webkit-scrollbar-thumb has a left and right padding to achieve that effect.

I have tried the following:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    background: #181818;
    width: 12px;
  }
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    padding: 0 4px; // This was supposed to do the trick
    background: #909090;
    border-radius: 100px;
    &:hover {
      background: #606060;
    }
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work...

*Result:*

[image: res]

Any ideas how to achieve the desired effect? **Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try faking the padding with `background-clip: padding-box` and applying a transparent border-right and left.

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background: #181818;
  width: 20px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  padding: 0 4px;
  border-right:4px solid transparent;
  border-left:4px solid transparent;
  background: #909090;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border-radius: 100px;
  &:hover {
    background: #606060;
  }
}

html,
body {
  height: 300%;
}
```

Comment: for some reason, the hover effect is bugged. when i hover over the scrollbar it loses the "padding" effect.

Comment: never mind. just changed the "background" attribute for "background-color" and the problem is now fixed.

Comment: Be careful with this technique, if the list becomes very long for the size, the padding-box will end up clipping the entire thumb from being visible. Maybe someday we will get good native support for custom scrollbars.